# How to get cart subtotal and subtotal in checkout shipping page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, knockoutjs, html

I want to show cart subtotal and subtotal on Magento 2 shipping page How to do that?

I have extended the file in my child theme but how to get these price details can anyone help me.

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you try any code?

Comment: yupp tried code from total.html like how magento did it in totals.html file like that i have tried but none of them working.

Comment: have you put the proper js and all?

Comment: No didn't change anything on js part just change in the html file.
Can you please tell me how to do that ?